# Run Google Assistant Command with an Android App

Tags: android, android-studio, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I want to be creating an Android App that could ask assistant to do something like, "Turn the TV on".

Google Home's Routine comes with it's own limitations, I am thinking of implementing the same with an app of my own. I tried going through the Google Assistant API but couldn't see anything that would allow app to send command **just like a user does**.

Could there be any possible way to make Google Assistant take command from an android app?

**Edit:** I want to be hard coding the command as text in code itself. Or, achieve a similar behavior somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can open like below and whatever you can speak it will reply accordingly.

```
   val launchIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND)
                      .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
   startActivity(launchIntent)
```